# [Azure, Keras], How can I load images from azure blob storage, into a Keras ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: azure, keras, azure-pipelines

I'm building an Azure pipeline to do image classification with a Keras model, and want to pass a data set to the Keras ImageDataGenerator function.

Code for the Pipeline train step is the following:

```
 datastore_path = [  
                     DataPath(datastore, "ds/Train/class1/*.jpg"),
                     DataPath(datastore, "ds/Train/class2/*.jpg"),
                     DataPath(datastore, "ds/Train/class3/*.jpg"),
                     DataPath(datastore, "ds/Test/class1/*.jpg"),
                     DataPath(datastore, "ds/Test/class2/*.jpg"),
                     DataPath(datastore, "ds/Test/class3/*.jpg")
                  ]

ds = Dataset.File.from_files(path=datastore_path)

pipeline_train = PythonScriptStep(name='02 Train Model', 
                                  source_directory=".",
                                  script_name='train.py',
                                  inputs=[ds.as_named_input('raw_data').as_download()], 
                                  inputs=[dataFolder],
                                  outputs=[datafolder],
                                  arguments=['--datafolder', datafolder,
                                  runconfig=self.run_config
                                  )
steps = [pipeline_train]
    
pipeline = Pipeline(workspace=self.ws, steps=steps)
```

And code for train.py:

```
# Get arguments from pipeline job 
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--datafolder', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

run_ = Run.get_context()
ws = run_.experiment.workspace
ds = run_.input_datasets['raw_data']

b_size = 10
size = 100

train_gen = ImageDataGenerator()

train_path = ???
train_images = train_gen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
                                        target_size=(size,size),
                                        color_mode="rgb",
                                        batch_size=b_size,
                                        shuffle=True,
                                        class_mode="categorical")
```

So my questions are how do I pass the location of the ds to ImageDataGenerator? And is it possible to pass a azure.Dataset to ImageDataGenerator, in order to use output data from the previous step? Or in some way get the location of the output folder (i.e., train_path = args.datafolder+"/ds/train").

I tried using DataPath(datastore, "ds/Train/), passing args.datafolder+"/ds/train/". But am currently stuck, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution and will leave it here, if someone else find this.

I changed this:

```
pipeline_train = PythonScriptStep(name='02 Train Model', 
                              source_directory=".",
                              script_name='train.py',
                              inputs=[ds.as_named_input('raw_data').as_download()], 
                              inputs=[dataFolder],
                              outputs=[datafolder],
                              arguments=['--datafolder', datafolder,
                              runconfig=self.run_config
                              )
```

To this:

```
 pipeline_train = PythonScriptStep(name='02 Train Model', 
                                      source_directory=".",
                                      script_name='train_ds.py',
                                      outputs=[outputs],
                                      arguments=['--iris_ds', iris_ds.as_named_input("iris_ds"), '--param1', pipeline_param],
                                      runconfig=self.run_config
                                      )
```

Which didn't solve the problem, but I wanted to send a DataSet object instead of a mount point reference. The solution was to refer to the training data (in train_ds,py) with:

```
path_train = os.path.join(mount_context.mount_point, "db_pipe/Iris/Train/")
```

Where db_pipe is the name of the datastore I wanted to use, I had only tried mount_point + folders, and datastore + folder. After listing the location of the data with the code below, I was able to find the location of the training data:

```
for root, directories, files in os.walk(mounted_path, topdown=False):
for i, name in enumerate(files):
    id = "file " + str(i)
    run_.log(id, os.path.join(root, name))
for i, name in enumerate(directories):
    id = "dir " +str(i)
    run_.log(id, os.path.join(root, name))
```